# Node- Promisify a Function that Contains a Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am using an npm package called [arp-a](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arp-a) which returns a list of network addresses.

From the brief docs, the `arp.table()` method looks like this:

```
arp.table(function(err, entry) {
  //console.log(entry) - 'entry' is an object like {ip: 192.168.0.1, mac: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff}
}
```

The `arp.table()` method evidently contains a loop and returns the arp table object by object, rather than returning an array of the objects.

I could return an array like this:

```
arp_table = []
arp.table(function(err, entry) {
  arp_array.push(entry)
}
```

But how can I 'await' the array (so that I can `.map()` it)?

I have tried to 'promisify' the `arp.table()` method using `util.promisify`, but then it only iterates once:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK
const util = require("util");
const arp_table = util.promisify(arp.table);
arp_table()
.then(r => console.log(x))
```

I have also tried putting the `arp.table()` method into a function with a promise, but this also does not work - returning the array before the table loops are complete:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK, EITHER
const arp_table = function() {
  var arp_array = [];
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    arp.table((err, entry) => {
      arp_array.push(entry);
    });
    resolve(arp_array);
  });
};

arp_table()
.then(r => console.log(x))
```

I have looked at other patterns for loops on SO, but, in this case, `arp.table()` is essentially a 'black box' and I am not sure how best to promisify its output

Comment: `arp.table()` in this case has no mechanism to notify the caller when the loop has terminated?

Comment: It appears this is the case, which means that what you are asking for is impossible. Either the creator of this package designed the API poorly, or this method is intended to loop infinitely (there's no cancellation, so that's still terrible API design).

Comment: not so far as I can tell - one would need to know how many entries were on the table, which is unknowable in most cases.

Comment: Then I'd say it's not doable. Either you must know how many tables there are (then you could count the number of callbacks being made) or the lib must provide a mechanism that notifies you when it's done.

Comment: @Mohrn It [doesn't](https://github.com/TheThingSystem/node-arp-a/blob/7e2df94c3d2268489aaffa56cc2a5d8307f63124/index.js#L31). It calls an async method, but swallows our ability to figure out when it's done looping.

Comment: Never mind, the library calls the callback with `null` when it is done looping.

Comment: -https://github.com/TheThingSystem/node-arp-a/blob/master/index.js

Then do a PR. Could be as simple as passing `table.length` (and maybe `i`) to `cb`- Do a PR to the docs instead and explain the callback-being-called-with-null thing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular library calls your callback with `entry` set to `null` for the second parameter when it has finished looping, so you can create a `Promise` like this:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const arp_array = [];
    arp.table(function(err, entry) {
      if (err) 
        reject(err);
      if (entry)
        arp_array.push(entry)
      else
        resolve(arp_array);
    });
});
```

Comment: edit: fixed inconsistent variable name and wrong `Promise` constructor signature, added error handling

Comment: Perfectly answers the question - and seconds ahead of @charlietfl, who provided an nearly identical solution

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code , the callback gets called in a loop but also gets called after loop ends with `entry` as `null`

So you can use a conditional to resolve the promise:

```
const arp_table = function() {
  var arp_array = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    arp.table((err, entry) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      if (entry) {
        arp_array.push(entry);
      } else {
        resolve(arp_array);
      }
    });

  });
};

arp_table()
  .then(r => console.log(x))
```

Comment: Perfectly answers the question - and only seconds behind @laptou, whose answer I have therefore accepted

Comment: Actually a little bit ahead of the other...but not splitting hairs

Comment: Many apologies - somehow the other response appeared first.  Thank you for your timely and excellent response, in any event.